# Extending a CPT by Created by another plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox, plugins

I'm using WooCommerce for my store, and I need to be able to extend the Coupon post type... I need to add a selectable attribute of `membership_term` ...

How do you extend a CPT created by another plugin? Is there an official hook that I'm not seeing to be able to modify an existing CPT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to 'extend', or how you want to extend it, but you can alter posts types with [`add_post_type_support`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support), [`remove_post_type_support`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_post_type_support), and [a few other functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Related).

You can add metaboxes to the post type with [`add_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) setting the `$post_type` argument to the name used to register your post type. (Examples are on the Codex page) Unless the original plugin provided a hook you won't be able to directly alter its metaboxes but you can use [`remove_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) to remove existing boxes and then add back a near clone of the metabox with your changes.

You will have to hook into [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) or [`admin_action_{$_REQUEST[action]}`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/admin_action_%7B%24_REQUEST%5Baction%5D%7D?version=3.4&file=wp-admin/admin.php) to save any additional fields you create.

Comment: So for example, the post type has a meta box with a bunch of attributes ... I need to add another one, so that when the post type is saved, it will be included.